# How to insert data to database like G2-01, G2-02

Tags: postgresql

this is old table:

```
                TABLE A                           TABLE B  
  |group_id|      |group_code|        |name|      |group_id| 
 GROUP-ID-002         G2                A        GROUP-ID-002
 GROUP-ID-003         G3                B        GROUP-ID-002
 GROUP-ID-004         G4                C        GROUP-ID-003
 GROUP-ID-005         G5                D        GROUP-ID-003
```

so, i want to add new column to TABLE B: member_code and i want my table be like this:

```
                NEW TABLE B  
|name|      |group_id|      |member_code|
  A        GROUP-ID-002        G2-01
  B        GROUP-ID-002        G2-02
  C        GROUP-ID-003        G3-01
  D        GROUP-ID-003        G3-02
```

My problem is i don't know how to insert if my `group_code` is `G2` and `member_code` will start `G2-01, G2-02..` when  `group_code` is `G3` will start `G3-01, G3-02....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window function row_number to get the count of the group_code, then concatenate that count onto the group_code.

```
select name
     , group_id
     , group_code || to_char(code_n, 'MI00') member_code
  from ( select b.name
              , a.group_id
              , a.group_code
              , - row_number(*) over (partition by a.group_code) code_n
           from a join b on (a.group_id = b.group_id)
       ) nb;
```

Note the "- row_number ..." actually generates a negative number which the to_char format converts into the requested "-nn" format.